# How to access value inside the $ when creating an authentication page in Angular-NodeJs app

Tags: angular, authentication

I'm creating an authentication for a login page, but when making SetHeaders the '$' is not working. whenever it is included inside a quote its is taken as a text but not as its intended value.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokeInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  intercept(req,nxt){
    let authService = this.injector.get(UserService);
    let tokenizedReq = req.clone(
      {
        setHeaders:{
          Authorization: 'Bearer ${authService.getToken()}'
        }
      }
    )
    return nxt.handle(tokenizedReq);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use backticks, so called [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.getToken()}`
```